# How to make background switch with mouse hover over button in Squarespace

Tags: javascript, html, css, squarespace

I need help with working with a feature in a squarespace website. When the mouse is hovering over one of the three menus on the frontpage the background should switch to match with the button hovered. I have done something similar in my own testing environment but I havent gotten the transitiong between background work in a smooth way.

What I have tried to do is to add a specific class that contains an image which is over the default one. However the transition works very weirdly and not in the way I intended. I tried to make it fade in and out. Any ideas on how to do this and inject it into squarespace?

Here is my js, css and html:

```js
const btn1 = document.getElementsByClassName('btn1')[0];
const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0];
const img2 = document.getElementsByClassName('img2')[0];
btn1.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
    wrapper.classList.add('img2');
  img2.style.opacity = '1';
  console.log('log');
});

btn1.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
  wrapper.classList.remove('img2');
  console.log('log');
});
```

```css
body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.l {
    cursor: pointer;
    width:10rem;
    height: 5rem;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.l p{
    margin: auto;
}
.btn1{
    background: green;
}
.wrapper{
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height: 100vh;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}

.default{

    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547129607-cb70df5e9b4b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80');
}
.img2{

    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520799163662-189c0284137b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=961&q=80');
}
.img3{
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534043464124-3be32fe000c9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1900&q=80');
}
.test2{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper default">
    <div class='l btn1'>
        <p>
            Header
        </p>
       </div>
       <div class='l btn2'>
        <p>
            Header
        </p>
       </div>
       <div class='l btn3'>
        <p>
            Header
        </p>
       </div>
    </div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about changing the img src when hovering the element in css using the `:hover` selector?

Comment: Are you trying not so much to transition between background-images as such (which you describe as working 'very weirdly') but to gradually fade out one background image while another one fades in - using transition or animation on opacity?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not entirely clear, but as far as I understood from the translation, I can offer the following solution:

```js
const imgs = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547129607-cb70df5e9b4b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520799163662-189c0284137b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=961&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534043464124-3be32fe000c9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1900&q=80'
];
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const btns = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.btn');
wrapper.addEventListener('mouseover', function(ev) {
  if (!ev.target.classList.contains('btn') || ev.target.classList.contains('active')) { return false; };
  btns.forEach((el, i) => {
    el.classList.toggle('active', false);
    if (el == ev.target) {
      wrapper.style.backgroundImage = `url('${imgs[i]}')`;
      ev.target.classList.toggle('active', true);
    };
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%; height: 100vh;
  background-image: none;
  transition: background-image .3s ease-out;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 10rem; height: 5rem;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn p { pointer-events: none; }

.active { background: green; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='btn'>
    <p>Header</p>
  </div>
  <div class='btn'>
    <p>Header</p>
  </div>
  <div class='btn'>
    <p>Header</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not enough clear, but I think I know what u want.

You can use `mouseover` and `mouseout` (or) `mouseleave` property in each element you want background image to change. Or use a `array` to multiple backgrounds images.
Here is a each case example:

One image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1448375240586-882707db888b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Zm9yZXN0fGVufDB8fDB8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" id="img" onmouseover="change(true)" onmouseout="change()">
        <script>function change(q=false)
{
    if(q == true)
    {
        document.getElementById('img').src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473448912268-2022ce9509d8?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1025&q=80';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('img').src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1448375240586-882707db888b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Zm9yZXN0fGVufDB8fDB8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60';
        }
}</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

More then one image (like a automatic slider):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
#img{
    transition: linear 2s;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
    </style>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1448375240586-882707db888b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Zm9yZXN0fGVufDB8fDB8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" id="img" onmouseover="t = setInterval(change, 3000);" onmouseout="change(true)">
        <script>
            var counter = 0;
var t;
function change(q = false)
{
    if(q == true)
    {
        clearInterval(t);
    }
    else{
        var imgs = ['https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473448912268-2022ce9509d8?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1025&q=80', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519821172144-4f87d85de2a1?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1231&q=80', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1448375240586-882707db888b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Zm9yZXN0fGVufDB8fDB8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60'];
        
        if(counter === 3)
        {
            counter = 0;
        }
        else{
        document.getElementById('img').src = imgs[0 + counter];
        counter++;
        }
        }
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this way, when mouse is over the image the images starts altern, and when mouse leaves img the slider stop in the current image.

Hope I helped!